# Getting concrete attribute within a HTML span tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**My problem:**
I'm using beautiful SOAP in Python, and i want to know how do i get the concrete attribute such as "data-hk".

[image]

My code at the moment:
[image]

The output of the code is km/L, but i want the data about HK. How do i specifically select the right attribute within the span?

Many thanks in advance.

I tried the above code, and I've stated the result and output of it above.

Comment: Instead of `.text` maybe try `.data_hk` ? or `.attrs['data-hk']`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HK = cars.find("span", class_="variableDataColumn")["data-hk"]
```